# How to use artifactory as proxy to get a package?

Tags: proxy, artifactory

I've really tried to understand artifactory and to use artifactory as a proxy to get packages and files from public registries and github but haven't got it to work yet.

Github repository key in artifactory:

> github.com

File I want:

```
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/archive/v0.37.2.tar.gz
```

I have tried to reach it through a machine with command:

```
wget https://artifactoryenterprise.corp.com/github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/archive/v0.37.2.tar.gz
```

But it just timed out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is relevant now, but I assume the issue is with the repo key "github.com" which is causing the DNS resolution difficult. Can you test out by creating a generic remote repository with repo key as "githubcom" and wget the file as below

> wget https://artifactoryenterprise.corp.com/artifactory/githubcom/nvm-sh/nvm/archive/v0.37.2.tar.gz